# Binomial distribution: Cumulative distribution vs Chernoff bound

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I am studying Chernoff bounds lately but I am not clear how this is better than cumulative distribution function for binomial distribution.

For example, let's say that `p = 0.3` and `n = 3`. I am interested in finding $Pr(X \geq 2)$.

If I do cumulative distribution, this will be `P(X = 2) + P(X = 3)`, and the answer comes out to be `0.21`.

But when I apply Chernoff bound for $Pr(X \geq 2)$, I get an upper bound of `0.6`. How is Chernoff bound any useful then? Why not just use cumulative distribution always as it seems to give better bounds. What am I missing?

(I used [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((e%5E%CE%B4)%2F((1%20%2B%20%CE%B4)%5E(1%20%2B%20%CE%B4)))%5E%CE%BC%20,n%3D3,%CE%BC%3Dn%20*0.3,%CE%B4%3D11%2F9) to find the Chernoff bound)

Comment: Suppose $n=1000$ and you want to find $\Pr(X>650)$  The cumulative distribution gives the exact value, but the Chernoff bound is a lot easier to compute.

Comment: @saulspatz so, you are saying Chernoff is only useful if value of $n$ is large, otherwise we better do just CDF?

Comment: Yes, if it's easy to compute the exact value, why would you want to approximate it?